# Transformation of random variables and joint distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Given a variable $y_i$, normally distributed with 0 mean and $σ_y$ standard deviation

$y_i$ ~ NormalDistribution[0,$σ_y$ ]

I want to obtain with *Mathematica*:

1. The distribution of:
   $x = \bar{y} = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}$
2. The joint distribution of  $ (x,y_i )$

Comment: What have you tried?  For example, have you seen the documentation on `TransformedDistribution` and `ProbabilityDistribution`?

Comment: @JimB . I tried this  `TransformedDistribution[Sum[y, {i, n}]/n, 
 y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]y]]`. The result is `NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]y]`. However, the correct result should be `NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]y / Sqrt[n]]`

Comment: You need to "index" the variable `y` or else *Mathematica* thinks it is a single variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how to get *Mathematica* to get the joint distribution explicitly for a general value of $n$ but here is how one can easily see the pattern to figure out the general solution.

First the distribution of the mean:

```
marginalDistribution = TransformedDistribution[Sum[y[i], {i, n}]/n, 
  Table[y[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], {i, n}], 
  Assumptions -> \[Sigma] > 0]
{#, marginalDistribution/.n->#} &/@Range[2,10]
```

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{2}}\right] \\
 3 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{3}}\right] \\
 4 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{2}\right] \\
 5 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{5}}\right] \\
 6 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{6}}\right] \\
 7 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{7}}\right] \\
 8 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{2 \sqrt{2}}\right] \\
 9 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{3}\right] \\
 10 & \text{NormalDistribution}\left[0,\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{10}}\right] \\
\end{array}
$$

So we see that the marginal distribution of $\bar{y}$ is

```
NormalDistribution[0, σ/Sqrt[n]]
```

The joint distribution of $\bar{y}$ and, say, $y_1$ is given by

```
jointDistribution = TransformedDistribution[{y[1], Sum[y[i], {i, n}]/n}, 
  Table[y[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], {i, n}]]
{#, jointDistribution /. n -> #} & /@ Range[2, 10] // TableForm
```

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{2} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{2} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 3 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{3} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{3} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 4 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{4} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{4} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 5 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{5} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{5} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 6 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{6} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{6} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{6} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 7 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{7} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{7} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 8 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{8} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{8} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{8} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 9 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{9} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{9} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{9} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
 10 & \text{MultinormalDistribution}\left[\{0,0\},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \frac{\sigma ^2}{10} \\
 \frac{\sigma ^2}{10} & \frac{\sigma ^2}{10} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] \\
\end{array}
$$

So the general distribution is a multivariate normal

```
MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{σ^2, σ^2/n}, {σ^2/n, σ^2/n}}]
```

The general form of the joint density function can then be found with

```
FullSimplify[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{σ^2, σ^2/n}, {σ^2/n, σ^2/n}}], {y, ybar}],
  Assumptions -> {σ > 0, n > 1}]
```

$$\frac{n e^{-\frac{n \left(n \text{ybar}^2+y^2-2 y \text{ybar}\right)}{2 (n-1) \sigma ^2}}}{2 \pi  \sqrt{n-1} \sigma ^2}$$

Comment: Anyway, I like your answer!  I'll have to look at it to understand (not obvious (to me) that this would be the solution).

Comment: @mjw Good.  Answers should always be scrutinized and challenged if desired.

Comment: Nice!  In addition to trying to understand the technique, I checked the marginal integrals.  Looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the distribution of $x=\overline{y}$ (Part I of your question):

```
a[n_] := Table[y[k] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], {k, 1, n}]; 
p[n_] := TransformedDistribution[Sum[y[k]/n, {k, n}], a[n]];
```

Now

```
x \[Distributed] p[5] (* n=5, for example *)
```

The result is

```
x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Abs[\[Sigma]]/Sqrt[5]]
```

Comment: I am not sure, but shouldn't be n instead of 5 here `TransformedDistribution[Sum[y[k]/n, {k, 5}], a]` ?

And what if I want to leave n, without assigning a value to n? 
Thanks @mjw

Comment: Oh yes, you are right!  I started with 10 and changed to five as I was trying it out.  I'll fix it ... Thanks!

Comment: Let's go with five because it is clearer.  The result is `NormalDistribution[0,\[Sigma]/Sqrt[5]]`.  Not sure why Mathematica puts `Abs[]` around $\sigma$.  Obviously, $\sigma>0$.

Comment: Yes, sure it is clearer. Do you have any idea of how can I use n as a parameter, without assigning a value to n?

Comment: `a[n_] = Table[y[k] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], {k, 1, n}];`

Comment: I receive this error: Table::iterb: Iterator {k,1,n} does not have appropriate bounds. Does it work on your laptop?

Comment: Okay, working on it.  Not only does `a[n]` depend on $n$, so does $x$ ...

Comment: The joint distribution is going to require some more thought since $y_i$ and $x$ are dependent ... One idea is that $x= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^n y_k + \frac{1}{n} y_1=\tilde{z}+\tilde{y}$, so the problem really reduces to considering the sum of two Gaussians.  We want the joint distribution of $x=\tilde{z}+\tilde{y}$ and $n \tilde{y}$.

Comment: But still, I have no idea of how to compute $ \bar{z} $  :(

Comment: $\tilde{z}$ is just taking the sum of $n-1$ of the $y_k$'s and dividing by $n$.